# Can't get nth node in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I try to write xpath expressions so that my tests won't be broken by small design changes. So instead of the expressions that Selenium IDE generates, I write my own.

Here's an issue:

```
//input[@name='question'][7]
```

This expression doesn't work at all. Input nodes named 'question' are spread across the page. They're not siblings.

I've tried using intermediate expression, but it also fails.

```
(//input[@name='question'])[2]
error = Error: Element (//input[@name='question'])[2] not found
```

That's why I suppose Seleniun has a wrong implementation of XPath.

According to [XPath docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates), the position predicate must filter by the position in the *nodeset*, so it must find the seventh `input` with the name `'question'`. In Selenium this doesn't work. CSS selectors (`:nth-of-kind`) neither.

I had to write an expression that filters their common parents:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'question_section')][7]//input[@name='question']
```

Is this a Selenium specific issue, or I'm reading the specs wrong way? What can I do to make a shorter expression?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Here's an issue:
>
> ```
> //input[@name='question'][7]
> ```
>
> This expression doesn't work at all.

**This is a FAQ**.

`[]` has a higher priority than `//`.

The above expression selects every `input` element with `@name = 'question'`, which is the 7th child of its parent -- and aparently the parents of `input` elements in the document that is not shown don't have so many `input` children.

**Use** (note the brackets):

```
(//input[@name='question'])[7]
```

This selects the 7th element `input` in the document that satisfies the conditions in the predicate.

**Edit**:

People, who know Selenium (Dave Hunt) suggest that the above expression is written in Selenium as:

```
xpath=(//input[@name='question'])[7]
```

Comment: I've tried this before: (//input[@name='question'])[2], error = Error: Element (//input[@name='question'])[2] not found

Comment: @culebrón: Probably this is how Selenium reacts when an XPath expression doesn't select anything. No node will be selected by this XPath expression if in the document there are less than two `input` elements with attr. `name` with value `'question'`

Comment: @Dimitre: no. Here's an intermediate expression: [error] locator not found: (//input[@name='question']), error = Error: Element (//input[@name='question']) not found. Works without parenthesis.

Comment: Then use Dave Hunt's answer -- this has better chances to be supported by what Selenium calls "XPath".

Comment: Note that Selenium will only interpret a locator as XPath if it starts with `//` or `xpath=` so starting with a `(` will default to attempt locating the element by identifier (`id` or `name`).

Comment: @Dave-Hunt: So, will `xpath=(//input[@name='question'])[7]` then be acceptable?

Comment: Note that for longer paths the whole path has to wrapped in brackets. E.g. //form[@id='test']//input[@name='question'][7] becomes (//form[@id='test']//input[@name='question'])[7]

Comment: @CarlPritchett, This has nothing to do with the length of the XPath expression, but the true reason is that the XPath `[]` operator has higher precedence (priority) than the Xpath pseudo-operator `//`. By definition the goal of using brackets is to override the default precedence/priority. This is one of the most FAQ in XPath and I have answers where this is explained in detail. For example see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3676557/36305

Comment: My answer above works in xpath but I couldn't get it to work in Selenium - I had to use the answer by @DaveHunt below

Comment: @CarlPritchett, It is quite possible that Selenium is a non-compliant (buggy) XPath implementation.

Comment: Parentheses! Thank you! I was loosing my mind on this one.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the 7th `input` with `name` attribute with a value of `question` in the source then try the following:

```
/descendant::input[@name='question'][7]
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `//` is an exact synonym for `descendant-or-self::`, so I don't think this would help.

Comment: You are correct, but `descendant-or-self` is not a direct synonym for `descendant`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

"NOTE: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents."