# How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm writing a Selenium testcase. And here's the xpath expression I use to match all 'Modify' buttons within a data table.

```
//img[@title='Modify']
```

My question is, how can I visit the matched node sets by index? I've tried with

```
//img[@title='Modify'][i]
```

and

```
//img[@title='Modify' and position() = i]
```

But neither works.. 
I also tried with XPath checker(One firefox extension). There're totally 13 matches found, then I have totally no idea how am I gonna select one of them.. 
**Or does XPath support specified selection of nodes which are not under same parent node?**

Answer (score 243, accepted):

**This is a FAQ**:

```
//someName[3]
```

**means**: all `someName` elements in the document, that are the third  `someName` child of their parent -- there may be many such elements.

**What you want is exactly the 3rd `someName` element**:

```
(//someName)[3]
```

**Explanation**: the `[]` has a higher precedence (priority) than `//`. Remember always to put expressions of the type `//someName` in brackets when you need to specify the Nth node of their selected node-list.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry I totally forgot the precedence things.. I just tried and it works!

Comment: @Kymair-Wu: I am glad this answer was useful to you. Here at SO the way of expressing gratitude is by accepting an answer (hint: click on the check-mark next to the answer). :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev  you are getting points for the same question over and over :p, thanks for the FAQ.

Comment: @Eytoss, You are welcome. And yes, I am getting most +1s for relatively simple answers -- not for the answers that I believe are my biggest achievements -- probably because everybody understands the former and almost nobody understands the latter :)

Comment: I would clarify, that //someName[3] stands for "third occurence of someName on a level", not just a "someName that is a third child in a row of all children". Though I fully understand what you wanted to say, the original formula may sound a bit incorrect.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH, Not exactly. The exact meaning, as per Spec is: "*Select all elements named 'someName', where each of which is the 3rd 'someName' child of its parent*"

Comment: Which is now equal to what I'm saying. 3rd "somename" of childs. Not 3rd child which is by chance "somename". In any case, maybe I'm just not a native speaker, thus I feel a minor change of meaning behind the formula.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH, No "on a level" means the 3rd 'someName' which is at a given level (from the top). Anyway, attempts to paraphrase the only normative document (the spec) can and often lead to incorrect interpretation and understanding.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH, I never said "that are the 3rd child of their parent". I said exactly what the spec says: that re the 3rd "someName" child of their parent. Please, try to understand this, or take a good XPath training. For XPath 1.0 I can recommend the 3rd module of this training course (which I happen to be the author of): http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH, Actually I saw that in the answer I didn't say "the 3rd 'someName' child of its parent". Thanks for noticing this. Corrected now.

Comment: And index start at 1. WHY?

Comment: @Maxence, In XPath any sequence position (indexing) starts at 1. This is postulated in the WWW Consortium XPath Specifications. See for example: https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xpath20-20020430/#eval_context . It says in the 2nd bullet: "...The position of the first item in a sequence is always 1 (one). ..."

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev What I meant was why start at 1 when almost everywhere else the indexes start at zero.

Comment: @Maxence, When you say "almost everyone" you really skip all XML/XSLT/XPath developers. And not only them. If anyone thinks that they should use 0-based indexing in the "ordinary" programming languages like C#, Java, etc., do have a look at Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual" book, where every (of the hundreds described) algoritm uses 1-based indexing... In fact, Skienna allocates an array of N+1 items when he needs to use N items, and "forgets" about the item at position 0. All his code references arrays starting at 1. The gains are in understandability and reducing errors in edge cases.

Comment: "Note also, `index values in XPath predicates (technically, 'proximity positions' of XPath node sets) start from 1`, not 0 as common in languages like C and Java."

Comment: @IvanChau, Yes, as discussed at length in the comments above

Comment: My especial thanks for this answer - the use of parentheses in this fashion has been a godsend to me, and until I found your answer I was starting to fear there was no workaround!

Comment: @AJM You are welcome. Yes, XPath is a wonderful language and starting to understand it   is fun. Please, feel free to upvote :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Cheers - and I had already upvoted - I think near close-of-day Thursday after trying your answer.

Comment: @AJM, Thanks. If you are interested in XPath, maybe you will like my courses on Pluralsight :) For example, how to create a new datatype such as BinarySearchTree entirely in XPath 3.

Answer (score 19):

There is no `i` in XPath.

Either you use literal numbers: `//img[@title='Modify'][1]`

Or you build the expression string dynamically: `'//img[@title='Modify']['+i+']'` (but keep in mind that dynamic XPath expressions do not work from *within* XSLT).

> Or does XPath support specified selection of nodes 
>   which are not under same parent node?

Yes: `(//img[@title='Modify'])[13]`

---

This `//img[@title='Modify'][i]` means "any `<img>` with a title of 'Modify' and a child element named `<i>`."

Comment: For some reason I needed to include the index before the attribute expression. For example, to find `td`s that were the sixth child of a `tr` and don't have empty content: `//tr/td[6][string-length(text()) > 0]`

Comment: @kopranb For an explanation, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006439/18771

Comment: Thanks for explaining about '//img[@title='Modify']['+i+']' (+1)

Answer (score 4):

There is no `i` in xpath is not entirely true. You can still use the `count()` to find the index.

Consider the following page

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <title>HTML Sample table</title>
 </head>

 <style>
 table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
 }
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
 }

 th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
 }

 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

 th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
 }
 </style>

 <body>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
    <th>Heading 6</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 2 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 3 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 4 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 5 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 </br>

 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Heading 7</th>
    <th>Heading 8</th>
    <th>Heading 9</th>
    <th>Heading 10</th>
    <th>Heading 11</th>
    <th>Heading 12</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 1 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 2 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 2 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 3 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 3 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 4 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 4 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Data row 5 col 1</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 2</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 3</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 4</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 5</td>
    <td>Data row 5 col 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

The page has 2 tables and has 6 columns each with unique column names and 6 rows with variable data. The last row has the `Modify` button in both the tables.

Assuming that the user has to select the 4th `Modify` button from the first table based on the heading

Use the xpath `//th[.='Heading 4']/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody/tr/td[count(//tr/th[.='Heading 4']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/button`

The `count()` operator comes in handy in situations like these.

**Logic:**

1. Find the header for the `Modify` button using `//th[.='Heading 4']`
2. Find the index of the header column using `count(//tr/th[.='Heading 4']/preceding-sibling::th)+1`

> **Note:** Index starts at `0`

3. Get the rows for the corresponding header using `//th[.='Heading 4']/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody/tr/td[count(//tr/th[.='Heading 4']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]`
4. Get the `Modify` button from the extracted node list using `//th[.='Heading 4']/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody/tr/td[count(//tr/th[.='Heading 4']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/button`

Comment: thanks a lot! i use it, but I came to `td[count(../preceding-sibling::tr/th[.='Heading 4'])]/following-sibling::td` that don't fall into `td[1]` every time that i don't have some heading :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//img[@title='Modify'][i]
```

is short for

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/img[@title='Modify'][i]
```

hence is returning the i'th node under the same parent node.

You want

```
/descendant-or-self::img[@title='Modify'][i]
```

Comment: Just `/descendant::img[@title='Modify'][$index]` will work fine. Also note that `[i]` predicate test for existence of `i` child element.

Answer (score 1):

(//*[@attribute='value'])[index]
to find target of element while your finding multiple matches in it

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for index variable

Let's say, you have found 5 elements with same locator and you would like to perform action on each element by providing index number (here, variable is used for index as "i")

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    string xPathWithVariable = "(//div[@class='className'])" + "[" + i + "]";
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathWithVariable)).Click();
}
```

It takes XPath :

```
(//div[@class='className'])[1]
(//div[@class='className'])[2]
(//div[@class='className'])[3]
(//div[@class='className'])[4]
(//div[@class='className'])[5]
```