# XPath: How to select a range of nodes in the node set?

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath

I want to select a range of nodes in a node set. I tried, but I cannot get the result.

**example.xml**:

```xml
<div>
    <p class="p1">a</p>
    <p class="p2">b</p>
    <p class="p3">c</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="p1">aa</p>
    <p class="p2">bb</p>
    <p class="p3">cc</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="p1">aaa</p>
    <p class="p2">bbb</p>
    <p class="p3">ccc</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="p1">aaaa</p>
    <p class="p2">bbbb</p>
    <p class="p3">cccc</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the second to third `p`nodes( have `class="p1"`), I wrote the xpath:
`"//div/p[@class='p1'][position()>=2 and position()<4]"`, But it failed.I guess that if every time `"//div/p[@class='p1']"` get one node, and its position is 0, so I can not get a node which position>=2 and position<4, so the result is none.But How can I write the xpath?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your guess is about correct.

> The (`[]`) has a higher precedence (priority) than (`//` and `/`). [[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676557/2998271)]

So you need to wrap XPath before position filter within brackets as follow :

```
(//div/p[@class='p1'])[position()>=2 and position()<4]
```