# xPath: Finding Element at Position N

Tags: xml, firefox, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath expression for a Selenium test. I'm a little confused as to how (if at all) I can pick a specific element of a return set.  I have a basic xPath expression to select all the `div` elements with a certain CSS class

```
//div[@class='step-title']
```

When I used a Firefox xpath extension, this expression returns 7 results

[image]

What I **want** to do is select the first (or second, third, etc) element of this result set.  However, my instincts for path syntax fail me, because the following

```
//div[@class='step-title'][2]
```

Returns all 7 matches again.

[image]

I've tried several variations, all with the same result.

[image]

The reason I want to select a specific element is to test a feature that re-orders something on a page — i.e. "Does the first div contain the text "Checkout Method".  If selecting a specific element is impossible, alternate suggestions on how to write a selenium test to accomplish my end goal would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Self help desk strikes again.  Per [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium), `[]` has a higher priority than `//`, so you need to wrap your clause in parenthesis.

```
(//div[@class='step-title'])[1]
```