# Trouble selecting nodes with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have the current HTML layout

```
<table> //table[1]
</table>
<table> //table[2]
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <p>
            &nbsp;
         </p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table> //table[1]//table[1]
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p>
                        INFO 1
                     </p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <p>
                        INFO 2
                     </p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <p>
                        INFO 3
                     </p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <p>
                        INFO 4
                     </p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table> //table[1]//table[2]
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p><strong>Name</strong></p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <p><strong>Quantity</strong></p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <p>Apples </p>
                  </td>
                  <td>10</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>  //table[1]//table[3]
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the data within `//table[1]//table[2]`, yet I keep getting a null HtmlNode (`System.NullReferenceException`) for the following:

**doesn't' work:** `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody//tr//td//table[2]//tbody//tr");`,

I am not sure why this occurs as when I try to get data for `//table[1]//table[1]` it works just fine with this syntax

**works:** `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody//tr//td//table[1]//tbody//tr");`

Am I misunderstanding how the indexing works with Html Agility Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//table[2]` return 2nd `<table>` element within **the same parent** because in XPath :

> The (`[]`) has a higher precedence (priority) than (`//` and `/`). [[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676557/2998271)]

In your case, there is only one `<table>` in each `<td>`, therefore the Xpath expression returned nothing. One possible solution is to put brackets to alter the precedence :

```
(//table[2]//tbody//tr//td//table)[2]//tbody//tr
```

Above Xpath get 2nd `<table>` element from all `<table>`s returned by the inner XPath `//table[2]//tbody//tr//td//table`. Then from that `<table>`, continue to return descendants `//tbody//tr` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to base this off of `tr`'s not sure why my other way did not work, but this way does work.

I basically moved my indexing to the next level above my table's. So within the first `tbody` each table thereafter is within a tr/td statement, and I simply  I constructed my HtmlNode to index off of the `tr`'s. Maybe Agility Pack works better if you broaden the selecting process? IDK.

Anyways...

For `table[2]//table[1]` I used:

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody//tr[2]//table");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr//td/p"))
...
```

*I Selected tr[2] as I had a tr/td before with a blank space if you note the example HTML above*

For `table[2]//table[2]` I used

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//tbody//tr[3]//table[1]");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr//td"))
...
```

For anyone having issues, try moving your search to a broader selection by pushing specific tags to broader ones.