# Xpath selecting 1+ nodes when using [1]

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

Given the following SOAP XML response:

http://pastebin.com/f57T8ctD (too large to display in here)

If I try to retrieve the nodes `<ssr>` with the next Xpath sentence:

```
//*[name() = 'ssr'][1]
```

What I am getting is the next:

```
<ssr xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRACC_14_1_1A">
  <type>CTCE</type>
  <status>HK</status>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <companyId>OU</companyId>
  <freeText>XXX//GMAIL.COM</freeText>
</ssr>
<ssr xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRACC_14_1_1A">
  <type>CTCM</type>
  <status>HK</status>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <companyId>OU</companyId>
  <freeText>XXX/SI</freeText>
</ssr>
```

Instead of only the first one as I have tried to select with the query.

Is there another way to select the different `<ssr>` nodes specifying the node number?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I also have tried to use //*[local-name() = 'ssr'] without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium)

Comment: You really should not use `name()` or `local-name()` for that. Declare the namespaces properly and use namespace prefixes, it's not that hard.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I have already used that without any success. I use them in the proper way always if I can, but don't know why they did not work this time with this reply.

Regarding the duplicate, sorry. I couldn't manage to find the answer as I did not know how to exactly describe my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets wrapping the entire XPath except the index :

```
(//*[name() = 'ssr'])[1]
```

See the following post for explanation : [How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium/3676557#3676557)

Comment: Wow, that was fast and it's working like a charm. Thank you so much!