# How to set value into textarea attribute using nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui-automation, ui-testing, nightwatch.js

I am working on nighwatch.js for web ui testing, I want to set value to a textarea, and textarea has an attribute which has my actual text, I am writing full textarea and how I am setting in following.

```
<div class="textarea-description">
    <textarea cols="50" class="myClass setText" data-def placeholder="text to be replaced using nightwatch"/>
</div>
```

I am trying to set value in above textarea's attribute **data-def placeholder** as following ways

```
browser.setValue('.textarea-description textarea[type=text]','nightwatch'); or
browser.setValue('.textarea-description textarea[data-def placeholder=text]','nightwatch'); or
browser.setValue('.textarea-description textarea[type=data-def placeholder]','nightwatch');
```

but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your all valuable suggestions, all suggestions provided by you was able to give good knowledge but unfortunately none of the suggestion worked. I have resolved it by using following.

```
client.setValue('.textarea-description textarea','new text to be write.');
```

Actually attribute "data-def placeholder" was using only watermark that was not actual text, so it is working.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. It wasn't about setting the attribute but rather setting the direct value in the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution but it works:

```
browser
.execute("document.querySelector('.textarea-description .myClass').setAttribute('placeholder', 'nightwatch');")
```

If you have jQuery you can make it a bit nicer:

```
browser
.execute("$('.textarea-description .myClass').attr('placeholder', 'nightwatch');")
```

Comment: Did you try both JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: No, i tried only first one., i will try second one and let you know.

Comment: Your textarea does not have a closing tag (see the edit I made on your question) and I think that might be an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath to get the attribute.

```
.useXpath().setValue('//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'text to be replaced using nightwatch')]@placeholder', 'nightwatch')
```

[How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
.assert.visible('div.textarea-description textarea.setText')
.moveToElement('div.textarea-description textarea.setText', null, null)
.mouseButtonClick('left')
.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "a"])
.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "nightwatch"])
```