# How to find each first descendant element using xpath?

Tags: xpath

Assuming I have this XML:

```
<p>
    <a>
        <b>
            <jedi></jedi>
            <c>
                <jedi></jedi>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <jedi></jedi>
            <c>
                <jedi></jedi>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</p>
```

and I want to select each first `jedi` appearance under `<a>` (2 results), regardless of the xml structure beneath `<a>`, how do I do this?

When I tried one of the examples below, all the `<jedi>` returned

1. `//a//jedi[1]`
2. `//jedi[ancestor::a][1]`

When I tried using brackets, below, only the very first returned and not each first.

1. (//a//jedi)[1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `//a/descendant::jedi[1]`

Example:

```
# tee < x >(java -cp Saxon-HE-9.5.1-5.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:- -qs:'//a/descendant::jedi[1]')
<p>
  <a>
    <b>
      <jedi>1</jedi>
      <c>
        <jedi>2</jedi>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>
      <jedi>3</jedi>
      <c>
        <jedi>4</jedi>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
</p>
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jedi>1</jedi><jedi>3</jedi>
```