# SQL Extractvalue Xpath Expression find first occurence

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, extract, find-occurrences

I'm trying to extract the first occurrence in an `xml` message like this;

```
NVL(EXTRACTVALUE(message,'//ElementValue[1]'),NULL) as ElementValue
```

I get error:

> XML - ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the XPath would return every first `ElementValue` in a parent element. To actually return only the first occurrence of `ElementValue` in the entire document, you need to use parentheses before position index :

```
(//ElementValue)[1]
```

Also read [@Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676557/2998271)