# How to Identify a Web element if there are two or more elements having exactly the same attributes?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Below is a Piece of Code having three elements with same attributes.
How do i access the third element(3<sup>rd</sup> div).

```
<pre>
  <div class="tab-bar ons-tab-bar__footer ons-tabbar-inner" qmx-tabs="">
    <div class="tab-bar__item ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabbarTabsList track by tab.page">

      <div class="tab-bar__item ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabbarTabsList track by tab.page">
        <button class="tab-bar__button tab-bar-inner qmx-tab-active" ng-class="{'qmx-tab-active' : $index === activeTabIndex }" ng-click="loadTab($index)">
      </div>


        <div class="tab-bar__item ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabbarTabsList track by tab.page">
          <button class="tab-bar__button tab-bar-inner" ng-class="{'qmx-tab-active' : $index === activeTabIndex }" ng-click="loadTab($index)">
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</pre>
```

I need to use **findElement(By.)**  method.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the findElement(By.) method you can use xpath to select the Nth element matching the descriptor

```
(//div)[3]
```

Alternatively you could use the findElement**s**(By.) method to find all elements matching the descriptor an getting the Nth element out of this list (or iterate over it if you need multiple elements)

Comment: I used **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/button/")).click();**  but got this error "The given selector //div[3]/button/ is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement."

Comment: Remove the last `/` to make it a valid selector

Comment: @PawanJuyal I'm having trouble with your HTML. Could you fix the indentation in your example? I think the problem is that the 3rd div is enclosed in a <b> tag. If thats the case you could try somethings like //pre/b/div/button

Comment: Use brackets: `(//div)[3]` to select div. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium.

Comment: alternatively, use css:  `div:nth-of-type(3)`

Comment: @RemcoW  sorry for that <b> tag. It wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: @RemcoW  I used driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/button").click();     and received this error "Element is not clickable at point (1126.3333129882812, 634). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal__content"></div>"  ** I even used selenium IDE's record feature. It also uses the same xpath which is working.**

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);  Appears to be working here. Still I'm confused as to why click() method won't work.

Comment: @PawanJuyal Seems like a modal is blocking the button. Try using a javascript click as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947832/how-to-click-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `By.cssSelector()`, also since your item is under a `<b>` tag,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tab-bar b > div.tab-bar__item"));
```

Additionally, looking at your code, you probably want to click it.  If you want to click it, then you need to click the button underneath it.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tab-bar b > div.tab-bar__item > button")).click();
```