# Index in xpath expression

Tags: r, xml, xpath

In a related post, 
[How to select specified node within Xpath node sets by index with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674569/how-to-select-specified-node-within-xpath-node-sets-by-index-with-selenium),
it is mentioned that there is "no index i in xpath".
I am trying to use an index in an R loop within an XPath expression such as

```
getNodeSet(xmlfile, '//first[i]/second/third')
```

Clearly, according to the above post it works perfectly when replacing 'i' with '1', but not e.g. for `i <- 1`.
However, the workaround in the above post (i.e. using `['+i+']`) does not seem to work.
Any ideas on how to make indices work in XPath expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'//first[i]/second/third'` is just a string. Therefore you can use the R string building function `paste0()` to make your own (R doesn't use `+` for string concatenation).

```
getNodeSet(xmlfile, paste0('//first[', i, ']/second/third'))
```

Comment: Or alternatively using `sprintf` you could do: `sprintf('//first[%d]/second/third', i)`