# Selenium IDE get element using xpath and index

Tags: testing, xpath, indexing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am trying to assert that three elements are visible. I set up the following command to store the xpath count:

```
storeXpathCount | xpath=//input[contains(@class,"k-formatted-value") and contains(@class, "call-timer-editor")] | x
```

and x="3", which is correct. Now, I want to assert that all three of those inputs are visible. so I do:

```
verifyVisible | xpath=//input[contains(@class,"k-formatted-value") and contains(@class, "call-timer-editor")][1] | 
verifyVisible | xpath=//input[contains(@class,"k-formatted-value") and contains(@class, "call-timer-editor")][2] | 
verifyVisible | xpath=//input[contains(@class,"k-formatted-value") and contains(@class, "call-timer-editor")][3] |
```

The first line evaluates to true, but the other (which are for sure visible) evaluate to false. How should I correctly index to the three inputs?

Comment: This question has been aswered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369342/cant-get-nth-node-in-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post code or link to the page you are automating I can only guess. Try this:

```
xpath=(//input[contains(@class,"k-formatted-value") and contains(@class, "call-timer-editor")])[2]
```